# Why is database not showing on Android Studio Device Monitor?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

It should be located in "data/data/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent", but it's not even there.

[image: img1]

Here is the content of the classes inside the database

[image: img2]

Comment: Please post code directly rather than as screenshots. Also did you run your app?

Comment: I did run it and I've also restarted the Android Studio, nothing has happened.

Comment: Where do you create an instance of the SOL helper?

Answer (score 0):

You created a database class, but are you calling it from somewhere?
Try to add this into your MainActivity, and then run it.:

```
CrimeBaseHelper cbh = new CrimeBaseHelper(this);
```

If your database file was created, then you good to go. If not, then you probably have some query syntax error in create table.